# Java.awt.Toolkit on Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Im developing an Android Java App which require the /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar for the Java.awt.*
It's size is 32.3MB and when I try to run the App, Eclipse is stuck in Launching New_configuration and I can't see the App starting on my device (I need to xkill Eclipse). Without exporting the rt.jar file the App starts. This is how I set eclipse.ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Any suggestion?

PS.
I need Java.awt because I'm trying to export my existing working project to Android, and this project is a bit complex and importing:

```
java.awt.Image;
java.awt.Toolkit;
java.awt.image.MemoryImageSource;
java.awt.Frame;
java.awt.MediaTracker;
java.awt.image.PixelGrabber;
```

Following parts of my code where previous classes are used:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(pathFile);
```

the method:

```
public Image getImage() {
 MemoryImageSource mis;
 mis = new MemoryImageSource(this.biWidth, this.biHeight, this.pixel, 0, this.biWidth);
 return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(mis);
}
```

the class:

```
public class JpegEncoder extends Frame {  //some code....  
final MediaTracker tracker = new MediaTracker(this);  //some code.... }
```

and

```
final PixelGrabber grabber = new PixelGrabber(this.imageobj.getSource(), 0, 0, this.imageWidth, this.imageHeight, values, 0, this.imageWidth);
```

I don't need this to show any image but just for computing some actions...

Comment: What makes you think that "Java.awt.*" from some random edition of the JDK will work on Android?

Comment: Thanks for reply @CommonsWare. So the problem is related to the Java.awt.
How can I use it? I edited the question in order to show why I need it... :(

Comment: You will need to rewrite your app to use native Android APIs, or third-party libraries that work on Android.

Comment: however I don't need awt for showing any images but just for computing... including the jar will not solve?

Comment: @pittuzzo I have same issue, have you got a solution? I want to compile java code to android so please share with me if you got any solution.